# 3D graphics showing a double symmetric hemispherical sector diagram

Tags: graphics3d

I never used Mathematica to plot something that can be considered non-trivial. I want to create a plot similar to the one used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector#/media/File:Kugel-sektor.png)
on the left, but with an equal (symmetric) cone on the bottom hemisphere, with a plane cutting the two hemispheres creating the two equal opposite spherical caps, and perhaps using some nice translucent effects. I am a bit lost. Could you please suggest any reference/link that I can study to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like;

```
theta = Pi/4;
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2],
  Sphere[],
  Cone[{{0, 0, Cos[theta]}, {0, 0, 0}}, Sin[theta]],
  Cone[{{0, 0, -Cos[theta]}, {0, 0, 0}}, Sin[theta]],
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -10^-6}, {0, 0, 10^-6}}, 1]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, so quick! Thank you! Yes, something like this. Do you know how I can remove the edges of the big cube enclosing the whole picture?

Comment: Use: Boxed -> False

Comment: Thank you Daniel !